# how to connect DJANGO app to AWS RDS connected to a bastion via SSH

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Is there a way to connect **Django** to a **private RDS** connected to a bastion via **SSH**?

My current AWS infrastructure has a **EC2 Bastion** in a **public subnet** and **two private subnets** where **postgres RDS DB** reside.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "aaaa",
        "USER": "bbbb",
        "PASSWORD": "cccc",
        "HOST": "xxx.zzz.us-east-z.rds.amazonaws.com", # RDS Endpoint
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

using the terminal i can ssh into the bastion and check the connection with RDS, OK.

Now i want to connect Django settings above to RDS so:

- i connected my RDS to https://dbeaver.com/ software (**result say: connected**!)
- On Django side now when I edited the settings.py above with the AWS RDS credentials
  and started django `python manage.py runserver` i receive the following error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "xxx.zzz.us-east-z.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.

My expectation was that since the DBeaver software is connected to my private RDS, i would be able to connect Django to the RD instance. (I have used this approach with a public RDS)

Is there something that i am missing on the approach?

Comment: I have same problem ... did you solve it

Answer (score 2):

This is a DNS issue. If you use the IPs to connect, you will probably resolve this.

But if you need name resolution to the database, I would suggest that you run django in AWS as well to use the private dns resolution.

Comment: The RDS endpoint above is the IP address of the database, i have used it normally on a PUBLIC instance before

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an SSH tunnel using putty or SSH clients

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-with-putty/

then connect to Django  using the link below

https://gist.github.com/mhulse/1954422

Comment: hum i will try PuttY but using DBeaver above, if i am not wrong achieve the same goal, no?